# Bootstrap sidebar dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

Is there a bootstrap-based sidebar navigation panel with a drop down? I've looked extensively and cannot locate one. Here is my current code (It creates a sub menu but the drop down is unfunctional):

```
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">    
               <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">     
                    <?php foreach ($this->container as $page): ?>
                        <?php if( ! $page->isVisible() || !$this->navigation()->accept($page)) continue; ?>
                            <?php if(isset($page->pages) && count($page->pages)):?>
                                <li class="dropdown open">
                            <a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                              <?php echo $this->translate($page->getLabel()) ?>
                            </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <?php foreach($page->pages as $subpage):?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $subpage->getHref();?>">
                                            <?php echo $this->translate($subpage->getLabel());?>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php if(isset($subpage->pages) && count($subpage->pages)):?>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <?php foreach($subpage->pages as $innerpage):?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php echo $innerpage->getHref();?>">
                                                        <?php echo $this->translate($innerpage->getLabel());?>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>       
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                            </ul>       
                                        <?php endif;?>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                </ul>
                                <?php else:?>
                                    <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>">
                              <?php echo $this->translate($page->getLabel()) ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php endif;?>                
                      </li>
                       <?php endforeach ?>
                  </ul>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same thing a few weeks ago. I have found the same issue with your code that was in mine so I edited your code, see below.

Try this:

```
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">    
           <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">     
                <?php foreach ($this->container as $page): ?>
                    <?php if( ! $page->isVisible() || !$this->navigation()->accept($page)) continue; ?>
                        <?php if(isset($page->pages) && count($page->pages)):?>
                            <li class="dropdown open">
                        <a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                          <?php echo $this->translate($page->getLabel()) ?>
                        </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <?php foreach($page->pages as $subpage):?>
                                   <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $subpage->getHref();?>">
                                        <?php echo $this->translate($subpage->getLabel());?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php if(isset($subpage->pages) && count($subpage->pages)):?>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <?php foreach($subpage->pages as $innerpage):?>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="<?php echo $innerpage->getHref();?>">
                                                    <?php echo $this->translate($innerpage->getLabel());?>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>       
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
                                        </ul>       
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </li>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php else:?>
                                <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>">
                          <?php echo $this->translate($page->getLabel()) ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php endif;?>                
                  </li>
                   <?php endforeach ?>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: All you did was change the class to dropdown? It's still not functional for me. It creates a submenu but the menu pops out like an overlay instead of dropdowning.

Comment: Not change, ADDED (just to clarify). I will play around with it and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <nav class="nav-sidebar">
            <ul class="nav">    
                <?php foreach ($this->container as $page): ?>
                    <?php if( ! $page->isVisible() || !$this->navigation()->accept($page)) continue; ?>
                        <?php if(isset($page->pages) && count($page->pages)):?>
                            <li class="dropdown open">
                        <a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                          <?php echo $this->translate($page->getLabel()) ?>
                        </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <?php foreach($page->pages as $subpage):?>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $subpage->getHref();?>">
                                        <?php echo $this->translate($subpage->getLabel());?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php if(isset($subpage->pages) && count($subpage->pages)):?>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <?php foreach($subpage->pages as $innerpage):?>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="<?php echo $innerpage->getHref();?>">
                                                    <?php echo $this->translate($innerpage->getLabel());?>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>       
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
                                        </ul>       
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </li>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php else:?>
                                <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>">
                          <?php echo $this->translate($page->getLabel()) ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php endif;?>                
                  </li>
                   <?php endforeach ?>
              </ul>
              </nav>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am curious, did you edit the base bootstrap.css file? I wonder if those edits might be messing with your code.